# Get records according to month names irrespective of value existence

Tags: php, mysql

I have to filter data for last 3 months from current date, so that would be to fetch data from Aug to Oct. But value exist for October only in mysql table, so now i want to display record in following format:

```
Month     Values
Aug          0
Sept         0
Oct          10
```

But my query only shows October month records as i dont have record for previous 2 months.
How can i do this. Following is my query.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(user_analytics_id)) > 0 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT(user_analytics_id)) ELSE 0 END as pic_views,
YEAR(user_profile_viewed_date) AS pic_viewed_year,
MONTHNAME(user_profile_viewed_date) as pic_viewed_month
FROM (`user_analytics`)
WHERE `user_id` = '1' AND `view_type` = 'picture'
AND `user_profile_viewed_date` BETWEEN '2010-07-28 04:23:56' AND '2010-10-28 04:23:56'
GROUP BY MONTH(user_profile_viewed_date) ORDER BY MONTH(user_profile_viewed_date) ASC
```

The above query is not working as i want it to. So pls help me on this..

Comment: it returns value for just existing month, in my case piv_views = 1, pic_viewed_year = 2010, pic_viewed_month = October, but i want to display months August, September and October and values 0 for non-existing months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another table with numbers `1 .. 12` and `LEFT JOIN` your table to it.

Comment: cant we find a solution without using anyother table...?

Comment: @Sudhir: I never seen any other solution.